# In an Ansible playbook, what is a better way to iterate over a list of objects and call a different role depending on that object's data?

Tags: automation, ansible

I am using Ansible to read in a YAML file containing a list of dictionaries. I then need to iterate through this list and call a different role depending on data within each list object. I have a solution that is working, but it seems so kludgy to me, that I wanted to find out if there was a better way.

I have defined a YAML file structure to provide the input to my playbook and I read that file into a variable with the `include_vars` module. I then use `with_items` to loop through the array one time for each role that I need to support (currently 6, but it may increase) and use a `when` clause to only `include_role` when the data in the object is correct for that role.

---

## Code

### Sample Input file:

```
---
objects:
  - type: type1
    name: obj_type1
  - type: type2
    name: obj_type2
  - type: type3
    name: obj_type3
```

### Sample Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: cf-host
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    objects_file: ''
  tasks:
    - name: Read objects_file
      include_vars:
          file: "{{ objects_file }}"

    - name: Handle type1
      include_role:
        name: type1_role
      vars:
        - type1_role_name: "{{ item.name }}"
      with_items: "{{ objects }}"
      when: item.type == "type1"

    - name: Handle type2
      include_role:
        name: type2_role
      vars:
        - type2_role_name: "{{ item.name }}"
      with_items: "{{ objects }}"
      when: item.type == "type2"

    - name: Handle type3
      include_role:
        name: type3_role
      vars:
        - type3_role_name: "{{ item.name }}"
      with_items: "{{ objects }}"
      when: item.type == "type3"
```

### Sample Role:

```
---
- name: Print name
  debug:
    msg: "Type 1 - Name is {{ type1_role_name }}"
```

The other roles are the same, but have `msg` set to "Type X - Name is {{ typeX_role_name }}" instead.

---

This leads to a skipped task for every item in the list when it does not match the type corresponding to the role. It also means that I have to loop through the same list multiple times (as many as types that I need to support). As mentioned, I already need to support 6 different types and that number may grow.

This solution seems like it would scale very poorly and would have terrible performance as the list and supported types become larger and larger. Is there a better way to do what I need to do?

---

## Better Solution

Using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53859851/9744341 as a base, I was able to come up with this as a better solution that I am happy with. Here it is in case anyone else has the same needs:

### Sample Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: cf-host
  gather_facts: False
  vars:
    objects_file: ''
    role_name_lookup:
      type1:
        role_name: type1_role
        tasks_from: type1_tasks
      type2:
        role_name: type2_role
        tasks_from: type2_tasks
      type3:
        role_name: type3_role
        tasks_from: main

  tasks:
    - name: Read objects_file
      include_vars:
          file: "{{ objects_file }}"

    - name: Call roles to create infra
      include_role:
        name: "{{ role_name_lookup[item.type].role_name }}"
        tasks_from: "{{ role_name_lookup[item.type].tasks_from }}"
      vars:
        inputs: "{{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ objects }}"
```

### Sample Role:

```
---
- name: Print name
  debug:
    msg: "Type 1 - Name is {{ inputs.name }}"
```

The other roles are the same, but have `msg` set to `Type X - Name is {{ inputs.name }}` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this code fit your purpose?

```
- name: Include roles
  include_role:
    name: "{{ item.type }}_role"
  with_items: "{{ objects }}"


- name: Print name
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.type }} - Name is {{ role_name }}"
```

Comment: I don't think the `item.type` will necessarily match the name of the role that I will end up calling, but I could make a lookup table to match them. I didn't realize that you could use a variable in the name of a role. Now that I know that from your answer, I can probably make something work. Thanks.